# Updating the same list with square values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to  declare a list in python3 and then update it with square values.
e.g.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

and Output should be the same list with square values:

```
list1 = [1,4,9,16]
```

I don't want to use another list.
Please help?

Comment: `list1 = [i * i for i in list1]`?

Comment: Just use a boring old loop?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog That replaces the list, not the values in the list.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal None of the answers in the "dupe" does it in-place.

Comment: You _could_ use a list comprehension and then do slice-assignment: `list[:] = [see comment above]`, but this will still create a new list temporarily.

Comment: @BilltheLizard OP should specify whether he meant a separate variable or a new list object.

Comment: @tobias_k: The below posted answer is also the 2nd answer of the dupe!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Does not mean that the dupe is a dupe, just that the answer does not do what OP asks for. (Well, in fact, it does now)

Comment: This looked like a funny way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3000471/4121573

Comment: @tobias_k there is a target of modifying a list in place, that is considered a dup to a target that is not modifying a list in place... It seems like the other dup target was a poor choice of dup target, but this is an exact duplicate of the target that is pointing to a duplicate that is not an adequate target...

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201926/in-place-replacement-of-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list-in-python) as a duplicate target that is adequate.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a slice-assignment with a generator expression:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> list1[:] = (x**2 for x in list1)
>>> list2
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

With the `[:]`, it changes the list in-place, and by using a generator `(...)` instead of a list comprehension `[...]` it does not create a temporary list (in case that's the problem).
(But note that if you have a reference to an *element* of that list, that reference will not be updated.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list1 = list(map(lambda x: x**2, list1))` but this doesn't work in place. It replaces the list. For doing it truly in place you loop over every item:

```
for i, x in enumerate(list1):
    list1[i] = x ** 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = list(map(lambda x:x*x, list1))
```

or:

```
list1 = [i*i for i in list1]
```